# How to calculate the inverse of a large matrix in the float type?

Tags: c++, matrix, floating-point

I use Gaussian elimination to invert the matrix, the matrix is 12 x 12.

The result is correct when finding a small matrix, but incorrect when the matrix becomes larger.

I guess it’s a floating point decimal precision issue.

Is there a way to calculate an accurate inverse matrix using single-precision floating point decimals?

```cpp
template<typename T = float>
inline bool inverse(const MATRIX<Mtx_Rt, Mtx_Rt, T>& matrix, MATRIX<Mtx_Rt, Mtx_Rt, T>& out, void* pTmp) {

       if (matrix.GetNumOfRow() != matrix.GetNumOfCol())
        return false;

    MATRIX<Mtx_Rt, Mtx_Rt, T> augmentedMatrix = MATRIX<Mtx_Rt, Mtx_Rt, T>(matrix.GetNumOfRow(), matrix.GetNumOfCol() * 2, (T*)pTmp);
    memset(pTmp, 0, augmentedMatrix._sizeof());

    //[matrix | identity]
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetNumOfRow(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetNumOfCol(); j++)
            augmentedMatrix(i, j) = matrix(i, j);

        augmentedMatrix(i, i + matrix.GetNumOfRow()) = 1.0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetNumOfRow(); i++) {
        int pivotRow = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < matrix.GetNumOfRow(); j++)
            if (augmentedMatrix(j, i) > augmentedMatrix(pivotRow, i))
                pivotRow = j;

        for (int k = 0; k < 2 * matrix.GetNumOfRow(); k++) {
            T tmp = augmentedMatrix(i, k);
            augmentedMatrix(i, k) = augmentedMatrix(pivotRow, k);
            augmentedMatrix(pivotRow, k) = tmp;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetNumOfRow(); j++)
            if (j != i) {
                T ratio;
                if (augmentedMatrix(i, i) != 0.0)
                    ratio = augmentedMatrix(j, i) / augmentedMatrix(i, i);
                else
                    return false;

                for (int k = 0; k < 2 * matrix.GetNumOfRow(); k++)
                    augmentedMatrix(j, k) -= ratio * augmentedMatrix(i, k);
            }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetNumOfRow(); i++) {
        T diagonalElement = augmentedMatrix(i, i);
        for (int j = 0; j < 2 * matrix.GetNumOfRow(); j++)
            augmentedMatrix(i, j) /= diagonalElement;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetNumOfRow(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetNumOfCol(); j++)
            out(i, j) = augmentedMatrix(i, j + matrix.GetNumOfRow());

    return true;
}

//The following is the test data
0x000001DEBFA44B70     0.00901737064    0.00851101335    0.00903018098    0.00852382369   1.71711508e-06   1.07878850e-05   1.07854212e-05  -5.71605915e-06       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000  
0x000001DEBFA44BA0     0.00851101428    0.00921893492    0.00835073180    0.00905865245   0.000142186589   6.97691357e-05   6.96772186e-05   0.000119451797       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000  
0x000001DEBFA44BD0     0.00903018005    0.00835073087    0.00916963257    0.00849018339  -0.000121859746  -5.83902292e-05  -5.83116416e-05  -0.000103386286       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000  
0x000001DEBFA44C00     0.00852382462    0.00905865245    0.00849018339    0.00902501121   1.86097168e-05   5.91026037e-07   5.80158485e-07   2.17815614e-05       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000  
0x000001DEBFA44C30    1.71710417e-06   0.000142186575  -0.000121859761   1.86097132e-05      0.141640529       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000    0.00899084471    0.00772444298   -0.00682374742   -0.00809014961  
0x000001DEBFA44C60    1.07878877e-05   6.97691430e-05  -5.83902220e-05   5.91027856e-07       0.00000000      0.122075945      0.122108623     0.0703755319     0.0109803220    0.00996958558   -0.00884070992   -0.00985144638  
0x000001DEBFA44C90    1.07854303e-05   6.96772186e-05  -5.83116343e-05   5.80155756e-07       0.00000000      0.122108623      0.122141339     0.0704018399     0.0109902890    0.00998063106   -0.00885062385   -0.00986028183  
0x000001DEBFA44CC0   -5.71606142e-06   0.000119451797  -0.000103386286   2.17815686e-05       0.00000000     0.0703755319     0.0704018399      0.110758379    0.00697547942    0.00992908329   -0.00901818927   -0.00606458541  
0x000001DEBFA44CF0        0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000    0.00899084471     0.0109803220     0.0109902890    0.00697547942      0.157142207      0.148548171      0.145359069      0.136765048  
0x000001DEBFA44D20        0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000    0.00772444159    0.00996958464    0.00998063106    0.00992908329      0.148548156      0.157674491      0.136261418      0.145387754  
0x000001DEBFA44D50        0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000   -0.00682374695   -0.00884070992   -0.00885062385   -0.00901818834      0.145359069      0.136261433      0.156348825      0.147251189  
0x000001DEBFA44D80        0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000   -0.00809014961   -0.00985144544   -0.00986028090   -0.00606458541      0.136765033      0.145387754      0.147251174      0.155873895
```

Comment: Unless you really want the inverse matrix it will be more numerically stable to use QR decomposition instead. See eg [Numerical Recipes](https://www.foo.be/docs-free/Numerical_Recipe_In_C/c2-10.pdf). Even then QR might do better than a naive algorithm like the above. But for a matrix that size I'd be more inclined to work in double precision anyway - there is little or no speed advantage using 32 bit floats over 64 bit doubles on modern CPUs unless arrays become very large.

Comment: @MartinBrown Numerical method? I have tried jacobian iteration. But because my matrix is not necessarily "diagonally dominant". I found it troublesome so I didn’t try it.

Comment: You might look into SVD algorithms. They often use an interative methods to improve accuracy which is critical for singular, or near singular matrixes.

Comment: You may need full pivoting, especially if the matrix is near singular.

Comment: @MartinBrown Single precision can be (almost) twice as fast if the critical parts of the algorithm are properly SIMD vectorized.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. You show some “test data”, but it looks like a dump of memory, not data ready for input. Make an [mre] that other people can easily compile, and run, including input data, observed output, and expected output. Test your code with some simple things, starting with the identity matrix, to search for outright bugs before concluding it is floating-point rounding issues. A 12×12 matrix is not large, so large errors may be caused by bugs rather than by rounding.

Comment: Re “I guess it’s a floating point decimal precision issue”: Do not guess. That is no way to perform software engineering. Form hypotheses. Test them. Examine the workings of the program.

Comment: If I re-interpret the decimal approximation given by your memory dump in a IEEE 754 double precision matrix, I find that it is badly scaled: the maximum eigenvalue is about 0.5 while the minimum eigenvalue is about 0.5e-11. It means that you'll get a hard time inverting this matrix in single precision floating point, whatever the algorithm used. Hence, you should question the requirement to perform the operations in single precision.

Comment: @chtz although that is true that SIMD float can be faster than double it is inevitably less accurate. Most decent numerical libraries for linear programming are in at least double precision since 32 bit float is rather short on mantissa precision and also dynamic range. The OP would be better off using reliable numerical library code for his problem rather than trying to DIY it.  I see someone has posted a nice answer to that effect. I've not come across TNT before it is rather neat!

Comment: @EricPostpischil  I have tested this function with 5x5 and 6x6 sizes. Random numbers were used. The test results are correct. "Test data" is from a 3D physics project. Because the code is complicated, I can't post it all.

Comment: Nobody said to post all of the code. When asking debugging questions on Stack Overflow, you should include a [mre]. That is a **minimal** set of code that reproduces the problem, including a `main` routine and data to reproduce the problem.

Comment: ' "Test data" is from a 3D physics project.'  - That explains the near singularity. You want to look at things like principal component analysis and SVD and avoid inversion straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Using Template Numerical Toolkit [TNT] https://math.nist.gov/tnt/
just requires few includes (no library to build) and line codes as below to compute the inverse using LU decomposition.
It is a template class so you can use it with float. I use it for double matrix size up to 2000 from more than 10 years.
TNT also includes QR, eigenvalue solver and SVD.

```
#include <tnt/jama_lu.h>

template <class T>
TNT::Array2D<T> inverse(const TNT::Array2D<T>& M)
{
    TNT::Array2D<T> LU(M);
    int nline = dim1();
    int ncol = dim2();
    TNT::Array2D<T> input(nline, ncol);
    for (int i = 0; i < nline; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ncol; j++)
        {
            if (i == j) input[i][j] = 1.;
            else input[i][j] = 0.;
        }
    }
    return LU.solve(input);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).